# problem with updating after upgrading to 22.04

Tags: upgrade, updates

upgraded from ubuntu 20 and all seemed fine but i keep running into Discover refusing to update packages.

i keep geeting: flatpack operation not allowed for user.

i tried flatpak uninstall --unused to no avail.
somehow i think it has nothing to do with flatpack but with some repo i had on ubuntu 20.

for example it wont update mesa, so i checked package list and things like:

```
libglu1-mesa/**jammy,now** 9.0.2-1 amd64 **[installed,automatic]**
libegl-mesa0/now 23.1.0~kisak1~f amd64 [installed,local]
libegl1-mesa-dev/jammy-updates 22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.3 amd64
```

not sure what ",now " means but did then remember i used kisak repo but this was obviously disabled during upgrade to 22.04.

but now, if i enable it i get a message: failed to obtain authentication.

i have no idea if any of this is related (flatpack errors, disabled kisal repo, the ,now things) but not sure how to get out of this mess.

############################
########### update: #######

i reenabled the kisak-ubuntu-kisak-mesa-focal.list
but if i do:
sudo ppa-purge -d focal ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa
i get:

```
Updating packages lists
PPA to be removed: kisak kisak-mesa
Warning:  Could not find package list for PPA: kisak kisak-mesa
```

if i just want to manually remove some of the kisak packages it seems the entire system will be uninstalled as a dependency.

any help greatly appreciated.